# Passing a string array to Redshift

Tags: c#, amazon-redshift, npgsql

I have a `List<string>` in C# which I would like to use in a query to Redshift. For example:

```
List<string> fieldStringList = new List<string>(){"field1","field2","field3"};
await using var conn = new NpgsqlConnection("My Connection String");
await conn.OpenAsync();    
await using var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT TOP 10 * FROM example WHERE field IN (:field);", conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("field", NpgsqlDbType.Array | NpgsqlDbType.Varchar, fieldStringList.ToArray());
```

This fails with the exception

> Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42883: operator does not exist: character varying = character varying[]

It looks like I am trying to compare a varchar to a varchar[]?

How should I pass the array to the Redshift query?

Answer (score 0):

The `IN` operator doesn't accept arrays. Try the following:

```sql
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM example WHERE field = ANY (:field);
```

Comment: Same problem. I think that works in Postgres, but not Redshift?

Comment: That's definitely possible - the above is indeed for PG (I don't know much about Redshift). There may not be a solution for that there...